Go func for running external command, occasionally getting error: file already closed
My function
func RunCommand(cmdPath string, cmdArgs string) (error) {
    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 10*time.Second)
    defer cancel()

    cmd := exec.CommandContext(ctx, cmdPath, cmdArgs)
    stdout, err := cmd.StdoutPipe()
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(stdout)
    err := cmd.Start()
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(1)

    go func() {
        defer wg.Done()
        for scanner.Scan() {
            doSomething(scanner.Text())
        }
        if scanner.Err() != nil {
            log.Errf("Error reading stdout, %v", scanner.Err())
        }
    }()

    done := make(chan error, 1)
    go func() {
        done <- cmd.Wait()
    }()
    wg.Wait()

    return nil
}

I am only able to reproduce this issue a few times where i get this error:  Error reading stdout, read |0: file already closed. My understanding is i am closing stdout prior to checking scanner.Err() but why is that happening. I am using cmd.Wait() in a go routine which should wait for scanner.Err() and then close stdout right?

why would wait return an err though, that only happens if cmd fails to run. But what i am seeing is that the command did actually run but scanner.Err() still had an err

The error is likely to be caused by the subprocess terminating unexpectedly.
Consider this example.  We start a bash loop printing every quarter second.  But one second later, a goroutine kills the process by pid.  Its output follows.
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "context"
    "log"
    "os"
    "os/exec"
    "sync"
    "syscall"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 10*time.Second)
    defer cancel()

    cmd := exec.CommandContext(ctx, "sh", "-c", "for i in $(seq 1 10); do echo $i; sleep 0.25; done")

    cmd.Stderr = os.Stderr
    stdout, err := cmd.StdoutPipe()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer stdout.Close()
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(stdout)
    if err := cmd.Start(); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    go func() { time.Sleep(1 * time.Second); syscall.Kill(cmd.Process.Pid, syscall.SIGKILL) }()
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(1)

    go func() {
        defer wg.Done()
        for scanner.Scan() {
            log.Print(scanner.Text())
        }
        if scanner.Err() != nil {
            log.Printf("Error reading stdout, %v", scanner.Err())
        }
    }()

    done := make(chan error, 1)
    go func() {
        done <- cmd.Wait()
    }()
    select {
    case <-ctx.Done():
        log.Fatal(ctx.Err())
    case err := <-done:
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
    }
    wg.Wait()

}

2024/09/18 22:34:44 1
2024/09/18 22:34:45 2
2024/09/18 22:34:45 3
2024/09/18 22:34:45 4
2024/09/18 22:34:45 Error reading stdout, read |0: file already closed
2024/09/18 22:34:45 signal: killed
exit status 1

If you want to handle the error differently, you can compare it to os.ErrClosed:
  if err := scanner.Err(); err != nil {
      if errors.Is(err, os.ErrClosed) {
        log.Printf("Program ended unexpectedly")
      } else {
        log.Printf("Error reading stdout: %s", err.Error())
      }
    }


Would moving scanner := bufio.NewScanner(stdout) to the go routine prevent such unexpected termination?

No, the termination isn't caused by anything you did . The program you invoked failed.  You can identify the error like above, and the program is likely to have a nonzero exit status (exactly what that means, is up to the program you invoked)
